# Two different Kinds of forward slashes in Java

Tags: unicode, unicode-normalization

While dealing with unicode encoded characters in Java, I used Normalizer to normalize it and convert it to a String. Below is the code I used:

```
input = "¼";
input = Normalizer.normalize(input,Normalizer.Form.NFKD);

output: 1⁄4.
```

The forward slash that the method used was `"⁄"` whose unicode encoding is `\u2044` as opposed to the regular forward slash that I am able to type using my keyboard which is `"/"` encoded as `\u002f`.

What is the difference between these and when should one be used over another?

Thanks in advance.

Rishit

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#Arithmetic) may be of use

Comment: The unicode mentioned is a fraction slash. I'd guess you don't want to use it unless you have preceeding digits.

Comment: The divider slash wouldn't be printable ASCII.  That's the only reason I could think to prefer the "/"... if you needed to output to some sort of ASCII only data or device.

Comment: This may help https://superuser.com/questions/922074/difference-between-unicode-fraction-slash-and-division-slash/922075

Comment: The cure is a global find `[⁄∕]` replace `/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode these days contains heaps of variations of the common non-letter characters, and [slashes are no exception](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=SLASH). (That's not even all of them - search for "solidus" to get some more.) You've got fraction slashes (your one), full-width slashes, division slashes (yup, that's separate from the fraction one), thick slashes, extra-thick slashes - the list goes on.

The good news is you get to decide what slash is appropriate for your context.

If you're wanting to normalise just because you don't want fractions to appear squashed into a single character, or you want *all* fractions to display identically (unicode obviously can't have a character for every possible fraction) then using this fraction slash is probably what you want to go with.

On the other hand, if you want to normalise because you want to reduce the set of available characters to those that can be easily typed on a standard keyboard, it's likely the standard forward slash you should go with.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Berry mentioned, `\u2044` is the [fraction slash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm) character.

It isn’t just a slash that looks a little different;  it has specific rendering behavior.  From [the Unicode specification, section 6.2, “Other Punctuation”](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch06.pdf):

> ***Fraction Slash.*** U+2044 FRACTION SLASH is used between digits to form numeric fractions, such as 2/3 and 3/9. The standard form of a fraction built using the fraction slash is defined as follows: any sequence of one or more decimal digits (General Category = Nd), followed by the fraction slash, followed by any sequence of one or more decimal digits. Such a fraction should be displayed as a unit, such as ³⁄₄ or [image]. The precise choice of display can depend on additional formatting information.
>
> If the displaying software is incapable of mapping the fraction to a unit, then it can also be displayed as a simple linear sequence as a fallback (for example, 3/4). If the fraction is to be separated from a previous number, then a space can be used, choosing the appropriate width (normal, thin, zero width, and so on). For example, 1 + THIN SPACE + 3 + FRACTION SLASH + 4 is displayed as 1 ³⁄₄.

Personally, I prefer the use of the fraction slash, as it makes fractions look better, like they’re professionally typeset.  But there are some contexts where an ASCII slash is better, such as monospaced text, or wanting all-ASCII output, or as Michael mentioned, limiting text to characters which can be typed on a keyboard.